# How do I build a Java Github Project in Eclipse with no maven & gradle files and no .jar files in the repo

Tags: java, git, eclipse, maven

I am trying to build a Java project I found on Github using Eclipse. 
The project has no maven & gradle files and no .jar files in the repo.
I am getting the following error when I try to build the project within Eclipse. 
"No actions available" Please see the images attached. 
This is the current repo I am trying to run, 
https://github.com/copley/The-Complete-Coding-Interview-Guide-in-Java.git

[image: Current Eclipse Project View]

[image: Build Path Screenshot]

[image: Build Path Screenshot]

Comment: Create a new Java project. Manually import the files. That is not configured as a Java project or a maven project (notice there is no M or J above the project folder in project explorer).

Comment: Looking at your image, I see a `pom.xml`? So why isn't this a Maven project?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The Git repository, that has been imported as a general project, contains a large number of small Maven projects. Instead of doing all this manually, _Smart Import_ can be used for that (see my answer below).

Comment: @howlger I don't generally follow off-site links. I answer based on the content **in** the question. Glad you investigated further.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The screenshot shows that the `pom.xml` file is located in a subfolder, which means it's one or more nested projects, not the general project itself. Please note, _Smart Import_ is also used when doing _Import Projects..._ in the _Git Repositories_ view. Of course you can do it manually which was the only way a long time ago, but these days the recommended way is to let Eclipse do it for you since it's easier and faster.

Comment: @howlger It's all good, but *The project has no maven & gradle files and no .jar files in the repo.* implies OP added that `pom.xml` - anyway, good to know about *Smart Import*.

Answer (score 1):

**Right-click the project** and choose ***Configure > Configure and Detect Nested Projects...***

This will detect and configure all the Maven projects that are contained in this repository, so you can edit or run them.